# Python insert comma every third character multi-line error

Tags: python

I am using python to try to insert a comma after every third character,
and it works fine if my text file is one line,
but is breaking for my multi-line text file

Input:

```
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
```

output:

```
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz,
bc, dfg, hjk, lmn, pqr, stv, wxy, z
b, cdf, ghj, klm, npq, rst, vwx, yz
, bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz,
bc, dfg, hjk, lmn, pqr, stv, wxy, z
```

Desired Output:

```
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz
bcd, fgh, jkl, mnp, qrs, tvw, xyz
```

CODE:

```
with open("input.txt") as main:
    words = main.read() 

res = ', '.join(words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3))

print(res)
```

Comment: You would need to use `.readlines()` instead of `.read()`, then loop over the lines and apply your comma-adding code to each one individually.

Comment: .readlines() produces an error of : TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Answer (score 1):

It’s because a newline is a character, so your program is adding a comma every three characters, that’s just not quite what you want. You can apply it to every line separately, like this:

```py
with open("input.txt") as main:
    words = main.readlines()

res = "\n".join(
    ", ".join(line[i : i + 3] for i in range(0, len(line), 3)) for line in words
)

print(res)
```